# How can I set min Idle http connection from HttpClients.custom()?

Tags: jakarta-ee, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, httpconnection

I'm creating a connection manager at client end using `HttpClients.custom()` and later setting all the necessary configurations.

What I'm looking for is to set min number of idle connection per route at all times. At present the idle connections get closed after keep alive time set in `keepAliveStrategy`. I have gone through multiple posts and Apache documents and this has not been discussed anywhere.

```
HttpClients.custom()
   .setMaxConnTotal(20)
    .setMaxConnPerRoute(5)
     .setHostnameVerifier(...)
      .setSSLSockerFactory(...)
       .setKeepAliveStrategy(...)
        .build();
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Why I'm asking this? Because every request which goes from client to server after keep alive time takes significant time in opening a new connection and results into a poor performance.

Answer (score 1):

Apache HttpClient does not proactively establish connections by design.

There are three options here:

1. Keep connections alive longer
2. Execute cheap HEAD requests every once in a while to keep the route always ready
3. Manually lease and release a connection for the given route.

Comment: ok2c, can you provide some reference for 3rd point? Most of the examples I have seen are using httpClient which creates connection at runtime.